# method in Python similar to myArray.remove("john") and case insensitive

Tags: python, arrays

is there a way in Python to remove all matches of a name, but make it case insensitive, similar to: myArray.remove("john")  ? i want to remove all instances of John and john from the array without having to write out a loop

Comment: @sedders123 It's not quite the same, because `remove` removes just the first instance, not all of them, and it does it in-place, and it raises an exception if nothing was removed, and the simple listcomp answer to that question won't handle any of those.

Comment: Yeah remove works differently but from the context it seems like the duplicate matches. I guess this needs clarification from the questioner.

Comment: By the way is this about list or array? It would be useful to have your input and desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `remove` for this, but you can easily write your own function that does it manually.

For example:

```
def remove_ci(lst, s):
    s = s.casefold()
    for i, elem in enumerate(lst):
        if elem.casefold() == s:
            del lst[i]
            return
    raise ValueError('remove_ci(x): x not in list')
```

---

Or, if you'd rather do it by copying rather than in-place mutation:

```
def removed_ci(iterable, s):
    s = s.casefold()
    for elem in iterable:
        if elem.casefold() == s:
            yield from iterable
            return
        yield elem
    raise ValueError('removed_ci(x): x not in iterable')
```

(You can make the second version a lot more concise with `itertools.takewhile`, but probably better to write out the loops and comparisons explicitly the first time you need to do something like this.)

---

Your question says you "want to remove all instances of…" But that's not what `list.remove` does; it removes only the *first* instance, and it raises an exception if there are no instances.

Comment: You apply the casefold to the wong item in the second approach.